# get status on specific date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Table structure: (database is `oracle 12c`)

```
CUSTOMER_ID | STATUS | STATUS_FROM_DATE
        101 | ABC    | 10-01-2015
        101 | PQR    | 27-02-2015
        101 | LMN    | 04-08-2015
        101 | ABC    | 08-09-2015
```

**Question:** How to get `status` of customer for specific date from above table?

For example:

```
CUSTOMER_ID | Input Date | Expected Output
        101 | 15-01-2015 | ABC
        101 | 27-02-2015 | PQR
        101 | 28-02-2015 | PQR
        101 | 10-09-2015 | ABC
```

In above example, 

`ABC` was the status of customer on `15-01-2015`, because this is set on `10-01-2015` and not changed till `27-02-2015`.

`PQR` was the status of customer on `28-02-2015`, because this is set on `27-02-2015` and not changed till `04-08-2015`.

Comment: Your expected output does not seem to jive with the input table.  Can you clarify this?

Comment: Yeah i think 2nd row should be like `27-02-2015 | PQR`??

Comment: @Bhushan... you sure for 27th Feb 2015 the status should be ABC and not PQR? if I interpret correctly according to ur expected output, the status for 4th Aug 2015 then should be PQR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lead analytic function to get the end of interval. Then just search using between.

```
select * from 
(

    select 
      customer_id, 
      status, 
      status_from_date, 
      nvl(lead(status_from_date) over (partition by customer_id order by status_from_date)-1,
          to_date('2099','yyyy')
         )as end_date
    from your_table

)
where your_date_here between status_start_date and end_date
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and +1)

Answer (score 2):

Using newly introduced row limiting clause in [Oracle 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55636),

```
select <your input date> as date_, expected_status
from myt
where status_date <= <your input date>
order by status_date desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and +1)

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3353d/4)

```
 with ranges as (
     select t.*, 
     lead(STATUS_FROM_DATE,1, (select sysdate from dual)) 
       over (partition by CUSTOMER_ID order by STATUS_FROM_DATE) as status_change
     from Table1 t
 )
 select r.status, s."Date", s."Expected Output"
 from ranges r
 inner join TestStatus s
    on s."Date" < r.status_change
  and  s."Date" >= r.STATUS_FROM_DATE;
```

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks, I fix it to match OP update. Now calculated status match desire output status.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and +1)